# DTD validation error with libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2, dtd

I try to validate some xml data with a dtd. For that I have to use libxml2.
The produced xml data looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <root>
            <vent id="1">
                <usb_device_id>1</usb_device_id>
                <usb_device_channel>2</usb_device_channel>
                <vent_box_id>3</vent_box_id>
                <vent_box_channel>4</vent_box_channel>
            </vent>
       </root>
```

My dtd looks like this:

```
    <!ELEMENT root (vent) >
    <!ELEMENT vent (usb_device_id, usb_channel, vent_box_id, vent_box_channel) >
    <!ATTLIST vent id (ID) #REQUIRED >
    <!ELEMENT usb_device_id (CDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT usb_channel (CDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT vent_box_id (CDATA) >
```

I use http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-valid.html#xmlValidateDtd on the parsed tree. With this setup I get the error message:

> element vent: validity error : Value "1" for attribute id of vent is not among the enumerated set

Where I am wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#id) => [Name=>NameStartChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attribute `id` is defined as having the type `ID`. That means it has to be a valid XML name and thus its first character must not be a digit but a letter. A description can be found [here](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/dtd_attribute_types_id.cfm) or even better in the W3C documentation itself: [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#id) and [Names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) (copied form BLUEPIXY's comment)

Comment: Makes sense to read the standard twice once in a while, thank you :)